# remove loops with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, loops

```
def demand_y(self, prices):
    markt_prices = prices.copy()
    y = [0]*len(prices)
    for mp in range(len(markt_prices)):
        for p in prices:
            if(p >= markt_prices[mp]):
                y[mp] +=1
    return y
```

I'm trying to plot a demand and supply chart and this function returns me the y data points (how many people are willing to buy for a specific price).

The functions works but I am sure there is a way to get it done more efficient with numpy.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the check next to one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
prices = np.array([10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 50])
print((prices[:, None] <= prices[None, :]).sum(axis=1))
```

Prints:

```
[6 4 2 6 4 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast comparison and sum by column:

```
>>> prices = np.random.rand(10)
>>> prices
array([0.5875545 , 0.25082088, 0.60516259, 0.74796803, 0.20443016,
       0.46121859, 0.52371397, 0.31880511, 0.26756963, 0.75844983])
```

```
>>> np.greater_equal.outer(prices, prices).sum(0)
array([ 4,  9,  3,  2, 10,  6,  5,  7,  8,  1])
```

```
>>> (prices[:, None] >= prices).sum(0)
array([ 4,  9,  3,  2, 10,  6,  5,  7,  8,  1])
```